# How to model a current source with a prescribed waveform in Simscape?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I know the Simscape [current source](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/currentsource.html) block, but this one can only model a

> current source with DC, AC and noise components.

Instead of an AC current, I would like to model a current wave that is defined based on a general current vector in time. Is there a block that can do this, or do I have to define a new block myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needed block is a [Controlled Current Source](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/controlledcurrentsource.html?searchHighlight=controlled%20current%20source).